# PHP Wildcard Search

Tags: php, arrays, regex

i tried to setup a wildcard search where the user could use % as a wildcard for each single unknown alphanumeric. this search runs in a loop and could happen several 1000 times a minute - thats why i look for the fastest possible code.

so this is what i tinkered - seems to work - but in my eyes looks horrible stupid? as i'm very new to this regex-thing - any idea/response/correction/improvement very welcome :)

is there not a better/cleaner/faster way than my rookie-coding???

```
$haystack = explode(',', str_replace('%', '.', strtoupper('DEISD, B%W951%, CCA828')));

$needle = strtoupper('BAW951L');

foreach ($haystack as $pattern) {
    preg_match('/^' . trim($pattern) . '$/', $needle) ? $match = 'true' : $match = 'false';
    // just for debug print what it does
    print(preg_match('/' . trim($pattern) . '/', $needle) . PHP_EOL);
    print($match . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: `.` will match much more than a single alhpanumeric. You could try `\w` instead (includes underscore) or more accurately `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: thanx phil :) you are of course right! but in my single purpose this is not a problem as the input is predictable just alphanumeric. what is your idea to the code in general - isn't there a faster way - because my solution takes about 30-50 times the computing time a simple in_array uses. but in_array i found no wildcard option ...